# jQuery UI Map V3 - Localized response

Tags: jquery-ui-map

Is there any way to get a localized response with jQuery UI Map V3? I mean, when I use `search` method to find a location, the `long_name` value is returned in English.

On API docs I can't find any reference to a `locale` param or something similar.

Do you guys know something about this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself. You can specify the language you want the responses on the `script` call, like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;language=es"></script>
```

Of course this is not a jQuery UI Map issue, it's just Google Maps API configuration.